# How to extend struct with some non POD fields so it can be used with std::aligned_storage?

Tags: c++11, memory, struct

I'm playing with some code found on net, some of You may know it :)
Using C++11 with this template I can not do this (for `T=std::string`):

```
struct some_struct_t
{
    T                           container;
    std::atomic<some_struct_t*> next;
};

typedef typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(some_struct_t), std::alignment_of<some_struct_t>::value>::type some_struct_aligned_t;
```

This compiles well, but if You try to touch `node->container`

```
some_struct_t* node = reinterpret_cast<some_struct_t*>(new some_struct_aligned_t);
```

You'll get Segmentation fault, because `std:string` is not initialized properly.

I don't want boost or classes, just plain C++11 and struct.
How can I extened my struct to work with std:string? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void* raw_storage = new some_struct_aligned_t;
some_struct_t* p = new(raw_storage) some_struct_t;
```

Though it's not clear what the point of the exercise is. Plain old `new some_struct_t` is guaranteed to allocate a properly aligned storage.

Comment: I was so concerned with `std::aligned_storag` that I did not saw that there is no `new` for `some_struct_t`. Maybe I'm just tired :) Thank You very much. This double `new` (tho, second one does not allocate any memory) is ok. And the explanation: this https://github.com/mstump/queues/blob/master/include/mpsc-queue.hpp is template implementation of Dmitry Vyukov MPSC node-based queue. But it does not work with non trivial-constructor data (lines 41, 60) and that was all about. I simplified details to make my question simpler. Once more thank You.